# Adding a filter to format Date values dynamically in Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, nunjucks, templating-engine

How might I check if a value is a date in Nunjuck so that I can dynamically add a date filter to control how it displays.

For example:

```
        {% if field.value === Date  %}
           It's a date. Apply Filter!
         <input type="text" value="{{field.value | dateFilter }}">
            {% else %}
            Not a date. Don't apply filter!
         <input type="text" value="{{field.value}}">
        {% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

If `field.value` is `Date` then `getTime` and other `Date`-methods is exists.

```
{{ field.value | dateFilter if field.value.getTime else field.value}}
```

or like that

```
{% if field.value and field.value.getTime %}
// It's a date. 
{% else %}
// Not a date.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Sadly it didn't work for me. The `if` after `dateFilter` just removes the date specific fields from the page entirely. What exactly is `field.value.getTime` doing? Cheers!

Comment: `field.value.getTime` equals to `Is field.value have getTime method?`. If it's true then `field.value` is date. I add to answer typical `if`.